# Angular Universal starter build errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, gulp, angular-universal

Cloned a repository as is https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.git and ran npm install, which successfully downloaded dependencies. However starting a project with npm start resulted in the following errors:

```
    [0] Hash: 85bf4f395734d9bd880ccd42ebf013da158a27f7                                    r Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.27
Child
    Hash: 85bf4f395734d9bd880c
    Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.27
    Time: 17667ms
                 Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
        main.bundle.js  2.82 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    main.bundle.js.map  2.74 MB       0  [emitted]  main
     [277] ./src async 160 bytes {0} [built]
        + 436 hidden modules

    ERROR in ./~/angular2-universal-polyfills/browser.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'es6-promise' in '/Users/yaroslavsalmin/Documents/angular universal/universal-starter/node_modules/angular2-universal-polyfills'
     @ ./~/angular2-universal-polyfills/browser.js 2:0-22
     @ ./src/client.ts

    ERROR in ./~/angular2-universal-polyfills/browser.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'es6-shim' in '/Users/yaroslavsalmin/Documents/angular universal/universal-starter/node_modules/angular2-universal-polyfills'
     @ ./~/angular2-universal-polyfills/browser.js 3:0-19
     @ ./src/client.ts

    ERROR in ./~/angular2-universal-polyfills/browser.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ie-shim' in '/Users/yaroslavsalmin/Documents/angular universal/universal-starter/node_modules/angular2-universal-polyfills'
     @ ./~/angular2-universal-polyfills/browser.js 4:0-18
     @ ./src/client.ts
Child
    Hash: cd42ebf013da158a27f7
    Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.27
    Time: 17641ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
        index.js  2.67 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    index.js.map  2.58 MB       0  [emitted]  main
     [259] ./src async 160 bytes {0} [built]
        + 419 hidden modules
```

What do I need to do to resolve the errors?

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: So I thought that it might be the case. It was 4.x, then I installed 6.x, but it didn't make a difference. I didn't find es6-promise package in package.json. I presume it's a peer dependency of another package.

Comment: Can you try `webpack --display-error-details` to see more error details?

Comment: @attomos Managed to get it work. The command above gave a bit more insight and it turned out some packages were missing. I reinstalled all missing packages and it's building now. Cheers for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to attomos I managed to get a more detailed error from webpack, which showed that some npm packages were missing. It's normal with npm when you install bulk dependencies. Reinstalled required packages and the app spun up with no issues.